# How to Generate Halide Function with float argument

Tags: c++, halide

I'm trying to create a (C++) helper function that transforms a lookup table that's computed in my C++ code into a Halide Func which takes a float as an argument and lerps between samples in the LUT.

The use-case here is that the user has generated a tone curve using a spline with a bunch of control points that we want to apply with Halide. So I sample this spline at a bunch of points, and I want to write a Halide function that lets me linearly interpolate between these samples. Here's my current attempt at this:

```c++
#include <Halide.h>

using namespace Halide;
using namespace std;

static Func LutFunc(const vector<float> &lut) {
    Func result;
    Var val;

    // Copy the LUT into a Halide Buffer.
    int lutSize = (int) lut.size();
    Buffer<float> lutbuf(lutSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < lut.size(); i++) {
        lutbuf(i) = lut[i];
    }

    // Compute the offset into the LUT along with the blending factor
    // for the 2 samples we'll take.
    auto y = val * ((float) lutSize - 1);
    auto index = clamp(cast<int>(y), 0, lutSize - 2);
    auto fract = y - cast<float>(index);

    // interpolate between the 2 nearest samples
    result(val) = (lutbuf(index) * (1.0f - fract)) + (lutbuf(index + 1) * fract);

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that if I then try to include this function into my Halide pipeline, I get this error:

```
Implicit cast from float32 to int in argument 1 in call to "f" is not allowed. Use an explicit cast.
```

**How can I explain to Halide that the argument to this function should be a float, rather than an int?**

Here's a short test program for the above, in case it's helpful:

```c++
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<float> lut = { 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 };
    auto f = LutFunc(lut);

    Buffer<float> testData(4);
    testData(0) = 0.05;
    testData(1) = 0.15;
    testData(2) = 0.25;
    testData(3) = 0.35;

    Func testFn;
    Var x;

    testFn(x) = f(testData(x));

    Buffer<float> resultBuf(4);
    testFn.realize(resultBuf);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << i << " = " << resultBuf(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(if there's an easier way to generate these lerping LUT functions (esp if it's able to take advantage of the sampler hardware on GPUs), I'd be interested to know about that too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found, the arguments to `Halide::Func` are *always* integer types (int32 by default); this is intrinsic to Halide.

Re: a better way to do lerping, Halide has a built-in `lerp()` helper: see http://halide-lang.org/docs/namespace_halide.html#a55158f5f229510194c425dfae256d530

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems it's not possible to do this with a Func(): Funcs seem like their intended use-case is to encapsulate a transformation on the source data -- they have a constraint that their arguments be integers, and the intended use case is to specify the pixel coordinates of the input.

I think the way to achieve this is to break it up into two parts: a method to transform my LUT into a Halide Buffer, and a second method that takes an Expr as an argument and returns an Expr, implementing the calculation inline, to which we pass the generated buffer.

Here's a revised version of my function that does what I want:

```
#include <Halide.h>

using namespace Halide;
using namespace std;

static Expr LutInterp(const Buffer<float> &lutbuf, Expr val) {
    // Interpolate the two values nearest the specified input.
    int lutSize = lutbuf.dim(0).extent();
    auto y = val * ((float) lutSize - 1);
    auto index = clamp(cast<int>(y), 0, lutSize - 2);
    auto fract = y - cast<float>(index);
    return (lutbuf(index) * (1.0f - fract)) + (lutbuf(index + 1) * fract);
}

static Buffer<float> LutToBuff(const vector<float> &lut) {
    int lutSize = (int) lut.size();
    Buffer<float> lutbuf(lutSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < lut.size(); i++) {
        lutbuf(i) = lut[i];
    }
    return lutbuf;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<float> lut = { 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0 };
    auto lutbuf = LutToBuff(lut);

    Buffer<float> testData(4);
    testData(0) = 0.05;
    testData(1) = 0.15;
    testData(2) = 0.25;
    testData(3) = 0.35;

    Func testFn;
    Var x;

    testFn(x) = LutInterp(lutbuf, testData(x));

    Buffer<float> resultBuf(4);
    testFn.realize(resultBuf);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << i << " = " << resultBuf(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'll proceed with this for the time being, and swap it out if I happen upon a better solution in the future.